# Is there a way to optimize a foreach with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How can I check an array of integers contain an integer value.

How can i do it in LiNQ.  I have to do it in LINQ Query..

Like:-

```
   Int test = 10;
var a = from test in Test
        where test.Contains(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
    select test.id
```

Currently I'm doing it through Extensions Method but the method is slow.

```
public static bool ContainsAnyInt(this int int_, bool checkForNotContain_, params int[] values_)
    {
    try
            {
                if (values_.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (int value in values_)
                    {
                        if (value == int_)
                        {
                            if (checkForNotContain_)
                                return false;
                            else
                                return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ApplicationLog.Log("Exception:  ExtensionsMerhod - ContainsAnyInt() Method ---> " + ex);
            }
}
```

I have to do it in an optimize way because data is huge...

Comment: I check multiple value like Contain..But Contains work only for String i have to work on int type value..

Comment: Why is it in a `try ... catch`? Are you planning on adding some rash casts to it?

Comment: It jst an part of logic..that i am using

Comment: It's not clear what your input is, or your desired output. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. It's quite possible that all you need is a `HashSet<int>`.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that the `try ... catch` you have is worthless.

Comment: @Jball: Ok...but any other option to boost the performance

Comment: You would need to explain your situation better before I'd be willing to make performance suggestions - see the link that @Jon Skeet provided.

Comment: Your `catch` block will is the C# equivalent of Visual Basic's infamous On Error Resume Next. Nasty stuff. To remedy this you should rethrow the exception with `throw;` immediately after logging it.

Comment: @Shivi did any of the answers help? Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases Linq is slower than a foreach.

You can just call the Linq Extension method:

```
int[] values = new[]{3,3};
bool hasValue = values.Contains(3);
```

It accomplishes the same thing as your extension method.

Answer (score 1):

Would the following not work faster (untested):

```
public static bool ContainsAnyInt(this int int_, bool checkForNotContain_, params int[] values_)
{
    if(values_ != null && values_.Contains(int_))
    {
       return !checkForNotContain_;
    }
    else
       return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working within your constraints, I would sort the arrays of values in each of the test classes so you could do something like:

```
int[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var results = from test in tests
              where test.BinaryContains(values)
              select test.id;
```

And the test class would look something like:

```
class Test
{
    public int id;
    public int[] vals; //A SORTED list of integers

    public bool BinaryContains(int[] values)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            if (values[i] >= vals[0] && values[i] <= vals[vals.Length])
            {
                //Binary search vals for values[i]
                //if match found return true
            }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Of course there are tons of ways you could optimize this further. If memory is not a concern, a Dictionary could give you all of the Test classes that contain a given integer.